# How to perform a Chi^2 Test with two data tables where x and y have different lengths

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics

So I have the following tables (simplified here):

this is Ost_data

| Raumeinheit | Langzeitarbeitslose |
| --- | --- |
| Hamburg | 22 |
| Koln | 45 |

This is West_data

| Raumeinheit | Langzeitarbeitslose |
| --- | --- |
| Hamburg | 42 |
| Koln | 11 |

Ost_data has 76 rows and West_data has 324 rows.

I am tasked with proving my hypothesis that the Variable "Langzeitarbeitslose" is statistically, significantly higher in Ost_data than in West_data. Because that variable is not normally distributed I am trying to use Pearson's Chi Square Test.

I tried

`chisq.test(Ost_data$Langzeitarbeitslose, West_data$Langzeitarbeitslose)`

but that just retuns that it can't be performed because x and y differs in length.

Is there a way to navigate around that problem and perform the Chi Square test regardless with my two tables which have varying lengths?

Comment: What are the rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pearson's ChiSq test is when the rows are measuring the same thing. It sounds like here your rows are just measuring some quantity on repeated samples, so you should use a t-test.

`t.test(Ost_data$Langzeitarbeitslose, West_data$Langzeitarbeitslose)`

Comment: No, Our rows are measuring the same thing. We are measuring the rate of long-term unemployment which is the variable Langzeitarbeitslose and we are comparing East germany with West Germany. Our tables Ost_data and West_data have different lengths because there is a much larger amount of Cities in West germany in comparison to east germany. We can't use the t-test because we don't have a normal distribution and because therefore we need a non-parametric test.

Comment: @GeoNerd The nonparametric equivalent of a t-test is the Mann-Whitney U test/Wilcoxon rank sum test `wilcox.test(Ost_data$Langzeitarbeitslose, West_data$Langzeitarbeitslose)`, which is used when you have independent samples from non normally distributed populations; but if your vector contains all the cities, you don't need to perform any test

Answer (score 0):

The most important aspect of your variable "Langzeitarbeitslose" (longtime-unemployed)is not whether it is normally distributed but its scale-level. I assume it is a dichotomous variable (either yes or no).

- t-Test needs interval-scale
- wilcoxon test needs ordinal scale
- chi-square test works for nominal (and therefore also for dichotomous) data

If you have both, the number of long-time unemployed and the number of not-longtime-unemployed per city you can compare the probability of being unemployed in the east and west.

```
l_west <- absolute number of longtime-unemployed in the west
l_ost  <- absolute number of longtime-unemployed in the east

n_west <- absolut number of observed people (unemployed or not) in the west
n_ost  <- absolut number of observed people (unemployed or not) in the east

N      <- n_west + n_ost # absolut number of observations

chisq.test(c(l_west,l_ost),p=c(n_west/N, n_ost/N)) 

# this tests whether the relative frequency of unemployment in the east (l_ost / n_ost)
# differs from the equivalent rel. frequency in the west (l_west / n_west)
# while considering the absolut number of observeations in east and west
```

I know the words Ost (east), West, and Langzeitarbeitslose (unemployed). I know that Hamburg and Köln are in the west and not in the east (therefore they should not appear in your "Ost_data"). Somebody who does not know this cannot help you. --> Bear this in mind in the future.

Best,
ajj